# Prevent the predictive text from learning a set of words

Tags: android

I am looking for an Android application that can prevent the predictive text from learning a set of specified words. If possible, compatible with Android 4.4.2. Gratis is better.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at [Ultra Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.binarybulge.android.apps.keyboard.full&hl=en_GB), there are [paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.binarybulge.android.apps.keyboard.full&hl=en_GB) and [trail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.binarybulge.android.apps.keyboard.trial&hl=en_GB) versions but both offer the option to blacklist words from the auto-correct.